# Object defined as object returns undefined

Tags: javascript

I am designating `player` as an object and within it are properties such as `weapon` which are objects I have defined as an item such as `stick` which will have a value attached to it that it could be damage. However, when called on by a function `player.weapon.stick` it will return the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'stick' of undefined". I believe it is saying weapon is undefined but the block I have defining all of this is

```
//Player Data
var player = {
weapon: stick,
speed: 3,
armor: cloth,
location: pLocation
}
var pLocation = [tickX, tickY];

//Items
var stick = { stick: 1 };
var cloth = { ClothArmor: 1 };
```

Is the issue within my defining of it or how I'm calling it `player.weapon.stick`

Comment: from your example you're missing some code, where is `tickX` and `tickY` defined?

Comment: You need to declare `stick` and `cloth` before using in `player`. `tickX` and `tickY` is not defined in example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several issues here, the biggest one being that you don't seem to understand objects (not trying to be rude, but you're using them waaay wrong).

```
var pLocation = [tickX, tickY]; // place this first to avoid undefined location
var player = {
weapon: stick, // stick without quotation marks is a variable, not a string, so this would be player.weapon = stick where stick = undefined variable.
speed: 3,
armor: cloth,
location: pLocation // since pLocation is defined after in your script i currently has no value, so location will be undefined.
}
//alternatively for pLocation
player.location = [tickX, tickY];

//Items
var stick = { stick: 1 }; // this creates an object called stick with a variable called stick with the value 1, so stick.stick = 1.
var cloth = { ClothArmor: 1 }; // this creates an object called cloth with a variable called ClothArmor with the value 1, so cloth.ClothArmor = 1.
```

So if you call player.weapon.stick it's incorrect because weapon is not an object, it's a variable inside an object. If you want player.weapon.stick you have to use:

```
player = {
    weapon: {
        stick: 'Variable value'
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry! I know I'm not too good at them I really learning as I go here and it was recommended I use an object for storage of player data instead of an array so I just did what I could, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

`cloth` and `stick` should be defined when you declare your `player`, since they're not defined yet their value is resolved to `undefined` and it won't change later on when you define them.

Answer (score 1):

It is best to define variables before using them

```
var pLocation = [tickX, tickY];

//Items
var stick = { stick: 1 };
var cloth = { ClothArmor: 1 };

//Player Data
var player = {
    weapon: stick,
    speed: 3,
    armor: cloth,
    location: pLocation
}
```

Answer (score 1):

JS only hoist functions - not variables. So, you have to define variables prior using them.

```
var pLocation = [tickX, tickY];

    //Items
    var stick = { stick: 1 };
    var cloth = { ClothArmor: 1 };

    //Player Data
    var player = {
    weapon: stick,
    speed: 3,
    armor: cloth,
    location: pLocation
    }
```

or

```
var stick

//Player Data
var player = {
weapon: stick,
speed: 3,
armor: cloth,
location: pLocation
}
var pLocation = [tickX, tickY];

//Items
stick = { stick: 1 };
var cloth = { ClothArmor: 1 };
```